# Sonar runner, seeonly newly introduced issues

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

is there a manner, using sonar runner, to see only the delta of the issues? For delta I mean only the issues introduced by recent changes?
If yes how?
Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the **Leak Period** of your project.

Default value is `previous_version`, which means you get the delta between last analysis and last version (defined in sonar-project.properties for example).

Based on your example, you want the delta between each analysis, so you need to set up the parameter to `previous_analysis`.

### Solution 1  : Setting using web interface

The easiest way to change the parameter is to use the sonar web interface as described in the documentation : [change the Leak Period](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setting+the+leak+period)

### Solution 2 : Setting using configuration file

If you **can't or don't want to use web interface** to set this parameter, use the configuration file `sonar-project.properties`.

1. Create or edit `sonar-project.properties` into the root folder of your project
2. Add the following line : `sonar.timemachine.period1=previous_analysis`

### Solution 3 : Set as a parameter of command line

The last solution is to add an argument of the command line to take into account the parameter. You have to add the argument `-Dsonar.timemachine.period1=previous_analysis` to your command line.

SonnarQube scanner options are defined in the [manual page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)

Comment: Hi Flows, how can I set this parameter? I'm using sonar runner on my local machine not on the sonar server so I've not a web interface. Where should I put this sonar.proerties file? And exactly what is the parameter key? Tnx!

Comment: The file `sonar-project.properties` (I edited my message) has to be on the root directory of your project. In the file, add the following line : `sonar.timemachine.period1=previous_analysis`

Comment: Hi again Flows, do you know if there is also a manner to pass this "sonar.timemachine.period1" parameter as a command line parameter without create a sonar-project.properties file?

Comment: You have to use -D option to set this parameter. I updated my answer. In your case, use `-Dsonar.timemachine.period1=previous_analysis`.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are using Visual Studio Team Services and git you have the option on getting new issues in a Pull request using this new feature they are rolling out.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/06/02/sonarqube-code-analysis-issues-integration-into-pull-requests/

Comment: Hi Ove, thanks for the answer but actually I'm not using Visual Studio, I'm using NetBeans with the radar plugin.